# os.path.join() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Tags: python, os.path

i'm getting python error:
**TypeError: join() takes exactly one argument (2 given)** in line 139, of set_Xpress method, which looks like this:

```
from os import path
from json import load
...
    def set_Xpress(Xpress_number, special_ts, disk, platform, testcase):
        ...
        with open("{0}:\\BBT2\\Configuration\\temporary.tmp".format(disk), "r") as test_conf_file_r:
            test_conf_vocab = load(test_conf_file_r)
        report = path.join(test_conf_vocab["report_dir"], test_conf_vocab["report_name"])
        ...
```

Please, help me understand what cause it. Python shell executes it with no problems, and the same stroke executed fine in another method with this tmp file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to be sure.. `import os` and use it as `os.path.join`

Comment: @Lipis i'll let you know about results. Though it's really strange that it's working on one place, not in another. I mean those imports i have.

Comment: @antontama: You seem to be convinced that the imports aren't working for some reason.  The error message you get is exactly what would happen if the imports worked just fine (you didn't get an `ImportError`, after all) but you accidentally set `path = '/some/path/here'` in the wrong place in your code.  Right before the `report = path.join...` line, add `print(path)` and see what it is.

Comment: @DSM Yes, thanks for understanding, you've cought my mistake. Fixed and thread is closed. Big thanks to everyone. I'll keep improving.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`path` is not the `os.path` module, it's a string. You redefined it somewhere.

```
from os import path  # path is a module, path.join takes many arguments

...

path = '/some/path'  # path is now a string, path.join is a totally
                     # different method, takes a single iterable
...

report = path.join(one, two)   # TypeError, str.join takes one argument
```

Answer (score 1):

[`os.path.join()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) takes any number of arguments. Are you sure your `path.join` is actually calling `os.path.join`?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely os.path.join() takes as many as argument,like the one who said you have definitely redefined the path as a new variable and stored as a string so,be careful about.Though i did absolutely this and after a long search and trial i found my error.